# I want more votes!

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Especially during the beta, I've been reading nearly all questions and answers, and I'm upvoting and downvoting a lot -- for two reasons: First, I hope to raise the content quality by making it clearer to newcomwers what a good and a bad *) post looks like, and second I want to motivate the users to continue contributing. The rep system works as a motivator because people like the "game" component; everybody wants to earn more rep, but only good posts make that happen -- and only if others actually vote!

**Problem:**
For the past three days, I've used up my 30 daily votes within an hour. **I want to have more votes to spend.**
I think it's safe to say that the system won't be changed, because the SE sites prove that it works well.  But **I want to know: Am I alone in this?**

**) "good and bad" in the spirit of SE: "this is useful" and "this is not useful".*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thank you for "spending" all your votes. Most sites have the opposite problem: Members are not voting enough!

**But if you *highlight* everything, then nothing gets highlighted.** I can remember watching a fellow student sitting to my left, incessantly highlighting every other sentence in his textbook as the professor spoke. All you end up with is one big block of *everything-is-important* so nothing-in-particular stands out.

Voting isn't there for you to personally pass judgment on everything in the system — deciding what is good and what is bad content, system wide. Voting is a currency for you to spend on the items you like MOST. An arbitrarily larger number of votes to distribute would mean that each vote means that much less.

Comment: Well said. And I agree with what you mean. I don't feel that I highlight quite that much. I'm not aiming to highlight everything, I'm aiming to increase the contrast between good and bad, move them into clearer blacks and whites, away from the gray middle ground. I feel that's important to do in a beta phase, because it shows direction for future postings. Perhaps I should simply spend more of my limited votes on downvoting (reasonably! and always with explanations), to gain that contrast.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how readily you give out your votes. I am big on upvoting, but I only upvote answers that I think are really worth it, not just every answer that has decent content.

Comment: True. I don't upvote *everything* but apparently my threshold of what's notable is lower than yours :-)

Comment: Either that or you spend a lot more time on the site than I do. :)

Comment: Heh, it's a new site and it's exciting to be part of the private beta. Good thing there's no activity graph here like what the chat room has :-)

Comment: lol, I never knew SE had chat until this morning. :D  Oddly enough, this is the first SE site that I have really gotten into... stack overflow is great, but I find little there that I can participate in other than looking for a specific question I have at the time. Here I can browse, find something interesting, and learn about a new facet of parenting or give my own advice. I like it so far! :)