# How do we get people to vote more?

Tags: discussion, voting

This is not a new topic, it was also [discussed in March 2011](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48/are-people-voting-enough). We can see [how many users vote, and how much](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/users?tab=voters).

Voting has many benefits:

- Good answers bubble to the top
- Good contributors are rewarded -- and reward is a [powerful motivator](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55/i-want-more-votes)!
- Users get more reputation points and [gain access to more features](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)

**How do we get people to vote more?**
(And how can we objectively measure whether they don't already vote a lot?)

Answer (score 4):

We can't force people to vote. There is no way to do it. No SE site has found a way, anyway.

I have my own set of rules in regard to voting:

- if I answer a question, I always vote. If I decide to "dignify" a question with an answer, I "dignify" it with a vote. Here on parenting it's always an upvote, not always so on SO.
- if I can understand the question immediately, I almost always eventually deem it worth upvoting. Short, simple questions are often the best questions
- questions difficult to understand deserve to be "put on hold". I don't usually downvote if I don't know what the question is about - but a temporary closure intil the question's problems are resolved works well.
- bad formatting and lack of puctuation marks is often a good hint for a downvote. If someone doesn't take the time to write the question properly, he usually doesn't take time to think it over. Many bad questions are terribly spelled.

Comment: I didn't mean force. I meant marketing, persuasion, encouragement.

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun I know you did, I actually did too. Still, no way to do it has been found yet.